# Multicast in java script

Tags: android, angularjs, sockets

I am trying to implement hybrid app using ionic and angularJS which will connect to multicast server to fetch HTML pages to connect to server. I am planning to use websockets for reliable connection.
server will send multicast packets in JSON format continuously. The client needs to join multicast group and read packet to figure out server ip address and port number from packet.

I have a couple of questions:

1. what will be the most reliable way to create multicast socket in the client to listen for server announcement message?
2. Is there any way to achieve this in hybrid approach?

I am able to receive multicast packets on nexus 9 using Java API, but i see most of the android devices don’t, or don’t fully, support multicast.
On IOS I don't have an issue.
As I am creating hybrid app, I am looking is there any better solution.

Comment: Define 'hybrid approach'. How many choices do you really have about how to create multicast sockets? Unclear what you're asking. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to utilize groups in SignalR in your server http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

This can catalyze your client side development https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub